# Questions about setting the First Responder in Xcode

Tags: xcode, first-responder

I'm just reading Apples' developer document of Xcode (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html)

We know that the difference between the two event handling mechanisms of target-action and responder chain is whether the target is set or unset(nil). But in the section of "To add new action messages to the first responder’s supported list" of that document, the step 5 reads
"Select the class in which the method will be defined from the pop-up list in the Type column". Does it mean that the target is will be set, so the action message is sent directly to the type specified in the xcode, instead of going through the responder chain. Within my understanding, that step is not necessary for programming the responder chain. Am I right?

Thanks.